# How to increase file path character limit

Tags: c#, file-io

How do you use the `\\?\` correctly to ensure that the file path size doesnt throw a took long exception at 250 characters? The code i have posted fails to work correctly.

Thank you

```
foreach (string filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
{
    String path = @"\\?\" + filePath;
    ...
```

Comment: Provide the error which the application is throwing here and also provide the complete code which you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

.Net 1.0-4.0 does not support long paths:

[more information on why .NET currently lacks built-in support for long paths](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx)